# When we implement lock-free data structures, why do we need to manage memory?

Tags: c++11, concurrency, lock-free

When we implement lock-free data structures, why do we need to manage memory? Consider the following stack example, why does the "delete old_head" statement  in the pop function , as the book say, cause problems to other threads? I don't see chances that "dereferencing a dangling pointer" can happen, and I run the code several times, not getting any error.

```
template<typename T>
class lock_free_stack
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        node* next;
        node(T const& data_) :
            data(std::make_shared<T>(data_))
        {}
    };
    std::atomic<node*> head;

public:
    void push(T const& data)
    {
        node* const new_node = new node(data);
        new_node->next = head.load();
        while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
    {
        node* old_head = head.load();
        while (old_head &&
            !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));
        auto res = old_head ? old_head->data : nullptr;
        delete old_head;
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: Imagine two threads enter `pop` at the same time. Both grab the same value for `old_head`. Then thread A proceeds all the way to `delete old_head`. Then thread B reads `old_head->next` via a now-dangling pointer, which exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: But , thread B reads old_head->next  through the compare_exchange_weak()  statement, which  can reset  old_head to the new head modified by thread A, then  in the next loop ,old_head->next is no problem.

Comment: No - thread B reads `old_head->next` and then **passes** the value thus read to `compare_exchange_weak` function (which then may or may not use it). As with any function call, evaluation of arguments *happens-before* the function body is executed.

Comment: Then there's another situation - the so-called [ABA problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem). Thread A initializes `old_head` and reads `old_head->next`. Then, right before it calls `compare_exchange_weak`, thread B executes `pop` twice and `push` once. Purely by accident, the now-free block that `old_head` still points to is reused for `new_node` in `push`. At this point, thread A proceeds to `compare_exchange_weak`. `head == old_head` so the exchange happens - but the value of `old_head->next` that thread A had loaded before the call is by now garbage.

Comment: Yes. How foolish I am. Thank you very much.